# Need help in data manipulation in R

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with 2 columns id, cat_list

```
id  cat_list
1          A
2        A|B
3      E|F|G
4          I
5    P|R|T|Z
```

i want to achieve the below using R code.

```
id cat_list1 cat_list2 cat_list3 cat_list4
1          A
2          A         B
3          E         F         G
4          I
5          P         R         T         Z
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit`.  Here, we don't need to worry to about the number of splits as it will automatically detect it.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, "cat_list", "|")
#   id cat_list_1 cat_list_2 cat_list_3 cat_list_4
#1:  1          A         NA         NA         NA
#2:  2          A          B         NA         NA
#3:  3          E          F          G         NA
#4:  4          I         NA         NA         NA
#5:  5          P          R          T          Z
```

NOTE: It may be better to fill with `NA` rather than `''`.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::separate` is handy:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate(cat_list, into = paste0('cat_list', 1:4), fill = 'right')
##   id cat_list1 cat_list2 cat_list3 cat_list4
## 1  1         A      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
## 2  2         A         B      <NA>      <NA>
## 3  3         E         F         G      <NA>
## 4  4         I      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
## 5  5         P         R         T         Z
```